# Moveit - fix a link with a virtual joint

Tags: ros, joint, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working on a robot-arm and I want to fix a link from my robot to the world.
I want to use the virtual joint option (and set a fixed joint) on the Moveit Setup wizard but afterwards, when I launch the demo.launch file and visualize my robot, the joint isnt working. It seems it is not taken into account at all,

I set the parent frame as ¨world¨ during the setup. Am I wrong?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240562/moveit---fix-a-link-with-a-virtual-joint/) by [Soho_](https://answers.ros.org/users/27617/soho_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you were working on the setup assistant, did you give the joint type as fixed?

If you give the joint as fixed, there will not be any visualization.

---

Originally posted by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) with karma: 95 on 2016-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-18**:
Sorry, I am confused as to what you mean by this.  If you do not set the virtual joint as fixed, what should it be set at?

I am working with a custom manipulator and can't figure out how to fix it to the gazebo world.  I have tried both the  gazebo tag, as well as fixing a dummy joint to the world via virtual joint, but no luck!